# Twitterの認証画面でのキャンセルボタンの検知

Tags: android, twitter4j

現在TwitterとAndroidを連携させたアプリを作っています。
Twitterの認証ページに飛ぶと「連携アプリを認証」と「キャンセル」というボタンがあり、「連携アプリを認証」を押すと認証が終わり投稿できるのですが、認証ページで「キャンセル」を押すと `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`というエラーが返ってきてアプリが落ちてしまいます。多分僕が予想するに、キャンセルボタンが押されても「連携アプリを認証」が押された時のような投稿処理が行われているのかなと思います。
　そこでキャンセルボタンが押されたことを検知したいのですが、検知する方法はあるのでしょうか？ご教授いただけますと幸いです。ちなみに`Twitter4J`というライブラリを使っています。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
            at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
            at twitter4j.HttpParameter.encode(HttpParameter.java:261)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.encodeParameters(OAuthAuthorization.java:384)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.encodeParameters(OAuthAuthorization.java:367)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.normalizeRequestParameters(OAuthAuthorization.java:351)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:198)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:250)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getAuthorizationHeader(OAuthAuthorization.java:66)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.setHeaders(HttpClientImpl.java:207)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:90)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
            at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:124)
            at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:138)
            at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:328)
            at com.example.appdev.ipsns.twitter.TwitterOAuthActivity$2.doInBackground(TwitterOAuthActivity.java:77)
            at com.example.appdev.ipsns.twitter.TwitterOAuthActivity$2.doInBackground(TwitterOAuthActivity.java:73)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: `RuntimeException` というのは了解です。おそらくその次に直接の原因となった例外内容が表示されていますので、例外をもう少し長め
に報告してもらえますか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。出力された例外を全て記載致しました。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: Hint: OAuth認可をキャンセルした場合、callbackで指定したURLにdenied={一時トークン}をGETクエリに入れてリダイレクトします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。キャンセルの場合はcallbackで指定したURLにdeniedが付くのですね。初めて知りました。これを参考に一度修正したいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth認証でキャンセルボタンが押されると、callbackで指定したURLにdeniedが付くので、deniedが付いていたら〜をするという処理にすると自分のやりたいことができました。
具体的に実装は以下のように行いました。

```
    public void newIntent(final Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null
                || intent.getData() == null
                || !intent.getData().toString().startsWith(mCallbackURL)) {
            return;
        }

            ・
            ・
            ・

            @Override
            protected AccessToken doInBackground(String... params) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("denied");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(intent.getData().toString());    //intent.getData().toString()でcallbackURLが取得できる
                try {
                    if (m.find()) {
                        //キャンセルが押された(callbackURLにdeniedが含まれていた)時の処理
                    }
```